# Jenkins in Docker container on AWS

Tags: docker, jenkins, amazon-ec2

I am setting up Jenkins on an AWS instance with

```
docker run -v jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home -p 8090:8080 -p 50001:50000 jenkins/jenkins:lts
```

I have opened ports 8090 and 50001 in the security group of the EC2 instance to reach it from the browser on my local computer. From my local computer, I can reach ports 50001 and 8090 while Jenkins is being set up. At port 8090, I am told that the website will automatically reload once Jenkins is set up.

Once the output of the `docker run` command tells me that Jenkins is set up, the website at port 8090 is no longer reachable, but port 50001 is still reachable. I can still reach port 8090 from within the EC2 instance, i.e. at localhost:8090, but not from my browser on my local computer.

What is going on? Do I need to configure an nginx server?

Answer (score -1):

check the ports locally on the AWS instance on a different shell window. you should see the jenkins container is up and 8090/50001 are accessible:

```
~ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                 COMMAND                  CREATED              STATUS              PORTS                                              NAMES
840f04633799        jenkins/jenkins:lts   "/sbin/tini -- /usr/…"   About a minute ago   Up About a minute   0.0.0.0:8090->8080/tcp, 0.0.0.0:50001->50000/tcp   relaxed_wozniak

~ nc -vz localhost 8090
Connection to localhost 8090 port [tcp/*] succeeded!

~ nc -vz localhost 50001
Connection to localhost 50001 port [tcp/*] succeeded!
```

Comment: From the EC2 instance, it works. But I can only reach port 50001 from my local computer and not port 8090.

Comment: If my EC2 instance is running at ip 1.2.3.4, "curl localhost:8090" works when executed on the EC2 instance itself. However, running "curl 1.2.3.4:8090" (or simply opening http://1.2.3.4:8090 in a browser) returns "Connection was reset". Interestingly, while Jenkins is starting up, a page "Jenkins is setting up" appears, but once setup, "Connection was reset" appears.